# How to shift filename numbers without collisions?

Tags: bash, rename, sort

Consider this list of files:

```
$ touch index-{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}.txt
```

If I want to shift them *down* so they start at zero, it's [relatively easy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9049373/96588):

```
$ rename --verbose 's/^index-([1-9])\.txt$/$1/; $_="index-" . ($_ - 1) . ".txt"' index-*.txt
```

This works because `man bash` specifies that globs are alphabetically sorted, so it will rename `index-1.txt` to `index-0.txt` *before* renaming `index-2.txt` to `index-1.txt`.

This breaks down if you want to shift *up*, or if the numbers have *different lengths*:

```
$ touch index-{10,11}.txt
$ rename --verbose 's/^index-([0-9]+)\.txt$/$1/; $_="index-" . ($_ + 1) . ".txt"' index-*.txt
index-10.txt not renamed: index-11.txt already exists
index-11.txt renamed as index-12.txt
index-1.txt not renamed: index-2.txt already exists
```

Possible long-term fixes:

- A `rename` option to try to reorder operations until there are no collisions.
- A `rename` option to move the files to a temporary directory first, and then move them back with the new name.
- A `rename` option to rename files in two steps, using unique names in the first step which won't collide with the original or new names.
- A way to do natural sorting + [reversal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34110/3645) of Bash globs.

Is there a simple way to get around this?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27382/how-do-i-reverse-a-for-loop if you're not averse to running rename in a loop. (You could reverse the list obtained in a loop if you want a single rename call I guess.)

Comment: @Mat No problem, but I was hoping to do it in less than four lines of code (not counting `;` trickery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@l0b0's solution rewritten for better robustness:

```
printf '%s\0' index-*.txt |
  sort --zero-terminated --field-separator - --key 2rn |
  xargs -0r rename --verbose '
    s/^index-([0-9]+)\.txt$/$1/;
    $_="index-" . ($_ + 1) . ".txt"'
```

Feel free to include in your solution and I'll delete my answer afterward.

Note that that and @l0bo's solutions are GNU specific, not Unix (GNU's Not Unix).

Comment: If you add a `--` parameter at the end and tweak the regex it actually works for `$'--$\`!*@\a\b\E\f\r\t\v\\\'"\360\240\202\211-'{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}$'\n'`

Answer (score 3):

There's a little known standard command on Unix that can help us here find a general solution in finding in which order a series of renames have to be done: `tsort`

Say we have a list of renames to be done in a file called `renames.txt` (assuming for sake of demonstration that their name doesn't contain blanks):

```
d a
e f
b e
a c
```

Because `d` is to be renamed to `a`, that means `a` must be renamed before `d`. So we've got a partial sort order there which would be the reverse of the order the files should be renamed.

`tsort` is the tool to infer a full sort order from a list of partial sort orders. It would return with an error if there was a loop which would help us detect cases where there's no solution. If we apply `tsort` on that input, it gives us:

```
b
d
e
a
f
c
```

Which says `b` should be renamed after `d` after `e`. We can use *GNU* `tac` (some systems also have `tail -r`) to reverse that order:

```
c
f
a
e
d
b
```

And join it with our list of renames:

```
tsort renames.txt | tac | awk '
  NR==FNR {
    ren[$1] = $2
    next
  }
  $1 in ren {
    print "mv -i --", $1, ren[$1]
  }' renames.txt -
```

which gives us:

```
mv -i -- a c
mv -i -- e f
mv -i -- d a
mv -i -- b e
```

which we can then pipe to `sh` to execute.

Note however that the above code is not robust in that we didn't check the exit status of `tsort` above to detect loops, and filenames mustn't contain any special shell characters.

The *robustification* is left as an exercise to the reader ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This works for the specific case above:

```
rename --verbose 's/^index-([0-9]+)\.txt$/$1/; $_="index-" . ($_ + 1) . ".txt"' $(printf '%s\n' index-*.txt | sort --field-separator - --key 2n | tac)
```

But:

1. it doesn't handle *whitespace* in filenames, and
2. it would be much more complicated for arbitrary filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question as you're mentioning bash, but with zsh, you can specify the sort order and numerical sort with globbing qualifiers.

```
$ echo index-*.txt
index-12.txt index-1.txt index-2.txt index-4.txt
$ echo index-*.txt(n)
index-1.txt index-2.txt index-4.txt index-12.txt
$ echo index-*.txt(nOn)
index-12.txt index-4.txt index-2.txt index-1.txt
```

Or you can define your own sort order with a function and use `index-*(o+that-function)`.

Also note that zsh has its own `rename` builtin function called `zmv`:

```
$ zmv -fvQ 'index-(<->).txt(n)' 'index-$(($1-1)).txt'
mv -- index-1.txt index-0.txt
mv -- index-2.txt index-1.txt
mv -- index-4.txt index-3.txt
mv -- index-12.txt index-11.txt

$ zmv -fvQ 'index-(<->).txt(nOn)' 'index-$(($1+1)).txt'
mv -- index-11.txt index-12.txt
mv -- index-3.txt index-4.txt
mv -- index-1.txt index-2.txt
mv -- index-0.txt index-1.txt
```

Comment: I'm looking for a Bash solution, as indicated by the tags.

Answer (score -1):

For context i use LapseIt Pro App to timelapse stuff & for some reason it stopped , i then restarted the timelapse but it gave it a different project name like :-

Proj10_img0000000x

I needed to rename all the 3000'ish files to a previous project 
Proj9_img0000000x & to amend the number at the end so the project had a continuous Name+Number feed so i could render all the images as one project video for example

Proj10_img00000001 --> Proj10_img00003249 needed to change to Proj9_img00004325 --> Proj9_img00007574

So all in all the end result looks like this in the project folder
Proj9_img00000001 --> Proj9_img00007574

If using Mac OSX ( i am using Mojave ) you can

1. In finder highlight all files to amend
2. Right click on a highlighted file section
3. Select Rename 'X amount' Items
4. A "Rename Finder Items" popup window opens
5. This popup window allows you to rename & renumber easily as well as a few other options which is handy.

I am still looking at command line grep/sed/awk/cut & find commands but for now the above method works ( i needed the video done asap for posting )

Comment: This is an OS X specific solution, and I'm looking specifically for a Bash solution, as tagged.